# SQL Difference between the purchase value of their first order and the second order

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I need help to get the different purchase values between customer first order and second order. For example, I know customer_id 12345 purchase their first order on 1/1/2021, and they purchase their next order on 1/12/2021. I can get the first order with MIN(Table1.date), but not sure how to get the next order date.
Please help! Your help is truly appreciated!

**I have 2 tables below:**

Table 1:
Description
All unique checkouts — one row per checkout
customer_id Customer id
cart_id     Unique cart id
date        Date of the cart checkout

Table 2:
Description
All cart-item combinations — each row is an item type in a cart
cart_id                cart id
item                   Item in a given cart
quantity               Quantity of item in a cart
price_per_unit_cents    Price per single unit of item in a cart

Comment: You can use a similar syntax to what you already have.  DISCLAIMER: Pseudo-code:  SELECT MIN(Table1.Date) to get your first one then join or union Table1 to another Table1 and do something like SELECT MIN(Table1.Date) WHERE Table1.Date NOT IN (SELECT (MIN(Table1.Date)).  Then that would also give you the next value you're looking for.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question with expected results; your question title referes to a difference, your body refers to different values. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is mainly standard SQL and works with recent versions of MySQL, PostgreSQL, plus others.

There are a few ways to do this.

This is a combination of a simple aggregate question, but also a window function issue, where we want to refer to adjacent rows in the basic aggregate result per customer/cart, by date.  The window function (`LEAD`) simply refers to the next subsequent result row based on the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Here's a simple test case.  It generates all rows for all customers, with the next cart total for each.  Notice the last row contains null, since there is no `next` cart total.

It's a little more than you requested, but contains some useful detail about how to produce more complex results, easily.  We can limit this to specific customers and specific orders, as needed.

Some of this can be simplified slightly, depending on the constraints and how your database handles functional dependence.
If cart_id is the primary key of table1, not just unique, we can simplify a little more.

[PG test case here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0084adf8f4dc59a3437098aef5107b3c)

```
SELECT t1.cart_id
     , t1.customer_id
     , t1.date
     , SUM(quantity * price_per_unit_cents)
     , LEAD(SUM(quantity * price_per_unit_cents)) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.customer_id ORDER BY t1.date, t1.cart_id) AS next
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.customer_id ORDER BY t1.date, t1.cart_id) AS n
  FROM table1 AS t1
  JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.cart_id = t2.cart_id
 GROUP BY t1.customer_id, t1.cart_id
 ORDER BY t1.customer_id, date
;
```

**The result (with a little more data to show the behavior):**

[image]

**The setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   customer_id    int         -- Customer id
 , cart_id        int  primary key -- cart id
 , date           Date        -- of the cart checkout
);

CREATE TABLE table2 (
   cart_id  int  -- cart id
 , item     int  -- Item in a given cart
 , quantity int  -- Quantity of item in a cart
 , price_per_unit_cents decimal(7,2)  -- Price per single unit of item in a cart
);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
   (1, 1,  5, 100.00)
 , (1, 2,  8,  50.00)
 , (2, 1,  5, 110.00)
 , (2, 2,  7,  60.00)
 , (3, 1,  5, 300.00)
 , (3, 2,  8,  50.00)
 , (4, 1,  5, 310.00)
 , (4, 2,  7,  60.00)
 , (5, 1,  2, 110.00)
 , (5, 2,  3,  60.00)
;

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
   (1, 1, current_date)
 , (1, 2, current_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY)
 , (2, 3, current_date)
 , (2, 4, current_date + INTERVAL '2' DAY)
 , (1, 5, current_date + INTERVAL '3' DAY)
;
```